# Bulk read of all documents in an elasticsearch alias

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following elasticsearch setup:

- 4 to 6 small-ish indices (<5 million docs, <5Gb each)
- they are unioned through an alias
- they all contain the same doc type
- they change *very* infrequently (i.e. >99% of the indexing happens when the index is created)

One of the use cases for my app requires to read all documents for the alias, ordered by a field, do some magic and serve the result.

I understand using deep pagination will most likely bring down my cluster, or at the very least have dismal performance so I'm wondering if the `scroll` API could be the solution. I know the documentation says it is not intended for use in real-time user queries, but what are the actual reasons for that?

Generally, how are people dealing with having to read through all the documents in an index? Should I look for another way to chunk the data?

Comment: in Elastic 7.X, you can use pagination: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the scroll API, Elasticsearch creates a sort of a cursor for the current state of the index, so the reason for it not being recommended for real time search is because you will not see any new documents that were inserted after you created the scroll token.

Since your use case indicates that you rarely update or insert new documents into your indices, that may not be an issue for you.

When generating the scroll token you can specify a query with a sort, so if your documents have some sort of timestamp, you could create one scroll context for all documents with `timestamp: { lte: "now" }` and another scroll (or every a simple query) for the rest of the documents that were not included in the first search context by specifying a certain date range filter.

Comment: Right. For some reason I didn't pick up on the fact that the documentation was discouraging its use for **real time** user queries...

Comment: There is a mention somewhere that keeping the cursor open also leads to more open file handles. But again I'm assuming this is only an issue when indexing is going on while the cursor is open?

Comment: No, this doesn't have anything to do with indexing. When you create a cursor you can specify the amount of time that the search context will be kept, that amount of time resets for every consecutive request you make, so if you define `5m` that means that the search context (or cursor) will live for 5 minutes after the last request you use it in. If you create many of these cursors it can affect your cluster performance, but again, I'm not sure it's relevant for your use case.